# How can i edit the value of a row in an entire Database

Tags: mysql, database

This is the deal, I have a column name "rid" this value is shown in almost all the tables in my Database, i need to change all values.
But i need to change values like this.e.g
set rid 1003428 where rid 1200000
one by one until rid 1204777

Comment: Generating a sequence the way you are proposing usually is not the best way to do it, and you may not need this at all.  Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: I need to do this, because I need to merge DBs, and New DB has RIDS starting from 1.200.000

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Im using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Try using bash scripting...

Sample

```
    for ids in {1200000..1204777}
    do
    echo 
    echo "Updating value at : $ids"
    mysql -u root -p****** databaseName -e "update tableName set rid = value where rid=${ids}"
    done
```